# Use RcppArmadillo to calculate the tail sum of the vector

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I wrote an R code to calculate the tail sum of a vector:

```
tailsum <- function(x){
   sum(x) + x - cumsum(x)
}
```

I hope to improve the efficiency of this function through RcppArmadillo, so I wrote

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
colvec tailsum_arma(const colvec &x){
  return sum(x) + x - cumsum(x);
}

NumericVector cumsum_self(const NumericVector &x){
  auto x_len = x.length();
  NumericVector y(x_len);
  y[0] = x[0];
  for(int i = 1;i < x_len; i++){
    y[i] = y[i - 1] + x[i];
  }
  return y;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector tailsum_cpp(const NumericVector &x){
  //just to compare with tailsum_arma
  return sum(x) + x - cumsum_self(x);
}
```

But to my surprise, R code is more efficient than RcppArmadillo code:

```
> x <- rnorm(1000)
> microbenchmark(
+     tailsum(x),
+     tailsum_cpp(x),
+     tailsum_arma(x)
+ )
Unit: microseconds
            expr min  lq  mean median   uq  max neval cld
      tailsum(x) 2.0 2.3 2.826    2.5 2.70 14.4   100   a
  tailsum_cpp(x) 1.9 2.1 2.495    2.3 2.60  6.5   100   a
 tailsum_arma(x) 2.2 2.4 3.128    2.6 2.85 30.4   100   a
```

How can I improve my code written in RcppArmadillo?(I need to use RcppArmadillo because there are many other linear algebra operations that are done using RcppArmadillo.)

Comment: Can't you just write this as a loop? As you did for cumsum.

Comment: Thank you!It really works!I rely on library functions so much that I never thought of using loops to accomplish this simple problem.@ F. Privé

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question, decent answer.  We can improve a little more:

- to be defensive, I recommend against `using namespace ...` and used explicit references "just to be sure"
- no need to include Rcpp.h, RcppArmadillo.h does all we need (and it's a no-op)
- your vector is too small to matter, I dialed up to 1e4, 1e5, 1e6 -- and then Armadillo sometimes ties R or beats it narrowly "in the mean"
- as we see, "basic" R operations are direct and lean calls to compiled code so you do not necessarily "beat them" (unless you use OpenMP and other tricks)
- why not combine both loops from tailsum_cpp and tailsum_self into one function to save calling overhead -- that ends up *fastest*
- still, I would *almost always* pick your first approach with Armadillo functions in a one-liner

Here is what I get with the small changes and larger vector, more runs:

```
Unit: milliseconds
  expr     min      lq    mean  median      uq     max neval cld
     r 3.09441 3.58882 7.46590 5.42797 6.79353 181.518   500   b
  rcpp 3.57488 4.16185 8.15100 5.83417 7.26449 146.467   500   b
  arma 3.09324 3.77172 7.63546 5.50456 8.21274 221.112   500   b
 combo 2.72539 2.87299 4.58357 3.16753 4.95350 109.923   500  a 
>
```

#### Code below

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::colvec tailsum_arma(const arma::colvec &x){
    return arma::sum(x) + x - arma::cumsum(x);
}

Rcpp::NumericVector cumsum_self(const Rcpp::NumericVector &x){
    auto x_len = x.length();
    Rcpp::NumericVector y(x_len);
    y[0] = x[0];
    for (int i = 1;i < x_len; i++){
        y[i] = y[i - 1] + x[i];
    }
    return y;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector tailsum_cpp(const Rcpp::NumericVector &x){
    //just to compare with tailsum_arma
    return sum(x) + x - cumsum_self(x);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector tailsum_combo(const Rcpp::NumericVector &x){
    size_t x_len = x.length();
    double x_sum = Rcpp::sum(x);
    double csum = 0.0;
    Rcpp::NumericVector y(x_len);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < x_len; i++) {
        csum += x[i];
        y[i] = x_sum - csum + x[i];
    }
    return y;
}

/*** R

# But to my surprise, R code is more efficient than RcppArmadillo code:

tailsum_r <- function(x){
   sum(x) + x - cumsum(x)
}

x <- rnorm(1e6)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(r = tailsum_r(x),
                               rcpp = tailsum_cpp(x),
                               arma = tailsum_arma(x),
                               combo = tailsum_combo(x),
                               times = 500)

*/
```

PS I had to remove the `auto` in the "combo" function as the compiler did some funky stuff with some of the returns. Here, for once, it helped to be explicit.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer and useful tips of C++ which help me a lot！@Dirk Eddelbuettel

Comment: @ChenHuang: You are welcome!  Feel free to "upvote" (click on up-triangle) and/or "accept" (click on tickmark only you as question asker see) to signal that the answer is helpful / answers your question.  That is StackOverflow signals and rewards between  answers.